# ion input textboxes should be visible until same as shipping checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, ionic-framework

I am working from my checkout cart page. I have input textboxes made for shipping and billing information to be filled out. 
I have a 'same as shipping' checkbox on the page that is not working correctly.
The goal is when the checkbox is not checked, the input textboxes for billing are visible.
When the checkbox is checked, the input textboxes for billing should be hidden.

I am using Angular 8 and Ionic 5 for this project.
I have added the ngmodel directive to the input tags.
I have tried the *ngif directive to hide the input textboxes. The issue with this is the textboxes are hidden already before checking the checkbox.
I have attempted to create a ionic form for the inputs, that was an unsuccessful attempt for me as well.
I have attached screenshots and can provide more if needed. Thanks in advance!

cart.page.html
[Shipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t8WK.png)

[Billing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnlhb.png)

cart.page.ts
[same as shipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj11i.png)

Comment: Rather than linking to screenshots, please copy and paste your code into your question.

Comment: Ok , instead of setting visibility for each element inside the ion-item, hive the ion-item an id , and pass it with sameasshipping method, and get element by id that is passed with the method and set its style to display none, and for ngModel binding, its not posible for dynamic lists since its one value binded for all lists, so when u trigger it once, it will be applied for all other checkboxes, so use id for main item, and if the utems where from ngfor, then depend on index of the ngfor to give values for the id (example field1, field2... ) , the numbers are the index.